# Counts not correct on Left outer joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query where I am getting counts of USRID's from the Left outer joined tables. The counts are off by 1 record in the PS_HS_AUD table, and also off by 1 record in the PS_HS_PRE table (total counts off by 2).

I believe the count is off because there is a USRID that exists both in the PS_HS_AUD table and another table called PS_HS_ANN, **AND** the USRID has 2 rows in the table PS_HS_ANN (each row has unique exam date). I have the below query that I added criteria to get the MAX EXAM_DT, hoping that it would get me the correct totals, but I am getting the same (incorrect) totals as before I added the MAX exam date criteria in the WHERE clause.

**Current SQL:**

```
SELECT 'ZTOTAL', '',  COUNT(G.USRID), COUNT(H.USRID), COUNT( J.USRID), 
 COUNT(M.USRID), COUNT(P.USRID), COUNT(S.USRID), COUNT(V.USRID), 
 COUNT(Y.USRID) 
FROM PS_JOB 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_ANN G ON  F.USRID = G.USRID AND G.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_ANT H ON  F.USRID = H.USRID AND H.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_AUD J ON  F.USRID = J.USRID AND J.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_DOT M ON  F.USRID = M.USRID AND M.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_HAZ P ON  F.USRID = P.USRID AND P.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_PRE S ON  F.USRID = S.USRID AND S.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_RES V ON  F.USRID = V.USRID AND V.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_HS_ASB Y ON  F.USRID = Y.USRID AND Y.EMPL_RCD = 
 F.EMPL_RCD

WHERE ( ( F.EFFDT = 
    (SELECT MAX(F_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB F_ED 
    WHERE F.USRID = F_ED.USRID 
      AND F.EMPL_RCD = F_ED.EMPL_RCD 
      AND F_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
 AND F.EFFSEQ = 
    (SELECT MAX(F_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB F_ES 
    WHERE F.USRID = F_ES.USRID 
      AND F.EMPL_RCD = F_ES.EMPL_RCD 
      AND F.EFFDT = F_ES.EFFDT) )
 AND (G.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(GG.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_HS_ANN GG
                  WHERE GG.USRID = G.USRID
                   AND GG.EMPL_RCD = G.EMPL_RCD
                   AND GG.EXAM_DT = G.EXAM_DT)  
     OR H.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(HH.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_HS_ANT HH
                     WHERE HH.USRID = H.USRID
                      AND HH.EMPL_RCD = H.EMPL_RCD
                      AND HH.EXAM_DT = H.EXAM_DT) 
     OR J.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(JJ.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_HS_AUD JJ
                     WHERE JJ.USRID = J.USRID
                      AND JJ.EMPL_RCD = J.EMPL_RCD
                      AND JJ.EXAM_DT = J.EXAM_DT)  
     OR M.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(MM.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_GHS_HS_DOT MM
                     WHERE MM.USRID = M.USRID
                      AND MM.EMPL_RCD = M.EMPL_RCD
                      AND MM.EXAM_DT = M.EXAM_DT)
     OR P.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(PP.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_GHS_HS_HAZMAT PP
                     WHERE PP.USRID = P.USRID
                      AND PP.EMPL_RCD = P.EMPL_RCD
                      AND PP.EXAM_DT = P.EXAM_DT)
     OR S.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(SS.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_HS_PRE SS
                     WHERE SS.USRID = S.USRID
                      AND SS.EMPL_RCD = S.EMPL_RCD
                      AND SS.EXAM_DT = S.EXAM_DT)
     OR V.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(VV.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_GH_RESP_FIT VV
                     WHERE VV.USRID = V.USRID
                      AND VV.EMPL_RCD = V.EMPL_RCD
                      AND VV.EXAM_DT = V.EXAM_DT)
     OR Y.EXAM_DT = (SELECT MAX(YY.EXAM_DT) FROM PS_HS_ASB YY
                     WHERE YY.USRID = Y.USRID
                      AND YY.EMPL_RCD = Y.EMPL_RCD
                      AND YY.EXAM_DT = Y.EXAM_DT) ))
```

**Query Results:**
[image]

The 5th column above (J.USRID) is showing a count of 5 records, even though as you can see from the below query on the PS_HS_AUD J table, there are only 4 records. (below table):

**PS_HS_AUD:**
[image]

If I query the PS_HS_ANN table, you can see that **USRID SD3925** (which also has a record in PS_HS_AUD) has 2 rows in the table. I believe this is what is causing the extra row to be counted in PS_HS_AUD (As if I comment out the join with PS_HS_ANN then my count shows correct as 4 records).

**PS_HS_ANN:**

[image]

The same issue is occuring with the PS_HS_PRE table as well (being duplicated because of this same USRID) What else can I use to prevent this from occuring? There will definitely be occurences where USRID will exist in multiple rows in each of these tables.  Thanks!

4/16/18 Update: Does anyone have any other ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to fix the problem is to do the aggregation *before* the `join`s.  Given the complexity of the query, that might be hard to implement.

The quick-and-dirty way is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT 'ZTOTAL', '', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT G.USRID), COUNT(DISTINCT H.USRID), COUNT(DISTINCT J.USRID), 
        COUNT(DISTINCT M.USRID), COUNT(DISTINCT P.USRID), COUNT(DISTINCT S.USRID), COUNT(V.USRID), 
        COUNT(DISTINCT Y.USRID) 
. . .
```

This is less desirable because each `COUNT(DISTINCT)` incurs overhead -- and pre-aggregating along each table eliminates that.  Plus, the intermediate results can get really big. also affecting performance.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other join that would work? I only want to grab a subset of what is in PS_JOB, but I want all data that is in the LEFT OUTER JOIN tables. Also when I do this then it will only display 1 unique USRID from PS_HS_ANN, when I still want the count's from the individual tables to include any with the same USRID. I'm just looking for it not to affect the counts on the other tables.